# What is the difference between standard Apollo subscriptions and 'Smart subscriptions'?

Tags: vue.js, vue-apollo

I'm not clear from the documentation what the key differences are between these standard Apollo subscriptions and 'Smart Subscriptions'.

The [docs](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/api/smart-subscription.html) say that any subscription declared in the apollo.$subscribe option of a Vue component will be a 'Smart Subscription.' It also seems to be that Smart Subscriptions will be automatically destroyed if the related query is stopped based on [this](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/apollo/subscriptions.html#alternate-usage).

If you call $apollo.subscribe() however, you just get a standard subscription, which is only killed when you destroy the component 
 based on the docs [here](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/apollo/subscriptions.html#standard-apollo-subscribe).

Is this variation in destruction criterion the only difference? Do normal subscriptions support the throttle and debounce options that smart subscriptions do?